# OnSubmit - all form fields are not sent - only few are sent across

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a HTML form and bunch of input fields along with a submit button.
When I click submit, I don't see all the fields being sent across on POST parameter values. I see only a partial list of parameters on firebug POST parameters list.

Here is my form code:

```
<form id="CalculatorForm" method="post">
<table id="t01" style="float: left; width:750px;">
<tbody>
<tr>
<th style="height: 90px; border-left: 1px solid; border-bottom: 1px solid;">Service</th>
<th class="auto-style-horizontalborders" style="width: 60px;">CPT© Code</th>
<th class="auto-style-horizontalborders">Total RVUs</th>
<th class="auto-style-allborders" style="width: 40px;">Average Number of Encounters (Daily)</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td id="E22" class="cpt">99254</td>
<td id="F22" class="rvu">4.69</td>
<td><input class="auto-style1 encounternumberdaily" id="G22" type="text"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td id="E23" class="cpt">99255</td>
<td id="F23" class="rvu">5.67</td>
<td><input class="auto-style1 encounternumberdaily" id="G23" type="text"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Critical Care</td>
<td id="E24" class="cpt">99291</td>
<td id="F24" class="rvu">6.26</td>
<td><input class="auto-style1 encounternumberdaily" id="G24" type="text"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td id="E25" class="cpt">99292</td>
<td id="F25" class="rvu">3.16</td>
<td><input class="auto-style1 encounternumberdaily" id="G25" type="text"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="auto-style-boldtext">Staffing with Physicians</td>
<td class="auto-style-boldtext" colspan="2">Your magic number:</td>
<td class="auto-style2 physician-count"><input class="auto-style1 encounternumberdaily" id="G26" type="text"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="auto-style-boldtext">How many Mid-Levels?</td>
<td colspan="2"></td>
<td class="auto-style3 physician-count"><input class="auto-style1 encounternumberdaily" id="G27" type="text"></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<table id="TableContactForm" style="float: left; margin-left:50px; border:none; width:150px;">
    <tbody>
    <tr><td>    <label>First &amp; Last Name</label> </td></tr>
    <tr><td>    <input class="fullname" type="text" name="fullname"> </td></tr>

    <tr><td>    <label>Email Address</label> </td></tr>
    <tr><td>    <input class="email" type="text" name="email"></td></tr>

    <tr><td>    <label>Phone Number</label> </td></tr>
    <tr><td>    <input class="phone" type="text" name="phone"></td></tr>

    <tr><td>    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" id="submit"></td></tr>    
    </tbody>
</table>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/wpsite/wp-content/themes/divi/js/EDEfficiencyCalculatorScripts.js"></script>
```

The values in the fields(G22, G23)) are not posted.
But values in fullname, email and  phone are sent across as parameters as below:
fullname=Santosh&email=Test&phone=123&submit=Submit

On submit, I am sending this form values to javascript and with ajax posting it to PHP server script.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: you need name="something" ...... Id's don't carry across page submissions

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the "name" attribute for these fields. I just added them to your form and it worked.